# C# DataContract Deserialization of URIs with multiple key=value terms

Tags: c#, serialization, uri, soapui, datacontract

I am using SoapUI to send URIs to a C# WCF Web Service (not REST) that uses the default deserializer for a DTO annotated with a DataContract ([DataContract (NameSpace ="mynamespace")].

The URIs may contain multiple key=value terms in their Query component: 
Example: `lookfor://3904?foo=this & that&bar=6`

- If I urlencode "this & that", but do not encode the & between the 2
  terms, then I will get a deserialization error from the server due to the  unencoded ampersand delimiter.
- If I urlencode the entire URI, then both ampersands will be encoded as %26. The web service will be unable to tell which ampersands are delimiters for key=value terms and which are parts of values and the code will fail.
- I could require that the ampersands be used to delimit the key value pairs be encoded as `&amp;` while the rest of the characters receive the standard URL encoding `lookfor://3904?foo%3Dthis%20%26%20that&amp;bar%3D6`. The `&amp;` will be deserialized as an ampersand. I could then delay urldecoding until after subdividing the Query portion of the URI using & as the delimiter (to get my key=value terms).

Is this the standard, professional way of handling this problem? I have googled and googled and can find no examples that deal with a URI with multiple key=value terms.

An alternative would be to double encode the ampersands in the values, and single encode the ampersands that are delimiters, but I did see (while googling)  warnings to never double encode.

Comment: You should use markdown syntax to make your question easier to read. Surround text inline with single backticks, \`. For example, \`code\` will show up as `code`. You can use this to output `&amp;` without it being escaped. See here for more details: https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax

Comment: How did you declare your endpoint parameters? Did you see this: https://www.soapui.org/rest-testing/understanding-rest-parameters.html ?

Comment: This is for a WCF/SOAP web service, not a REST service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's break it down.

The values you have are `foo = this&that` and `bar = 6`.

The first thing you need to do is URL encode the values, so you get `foo = this%26that` and `bar = 6`.

Then set those values as query string parameters, as

`lookfor://3904?foo=this%26that&bar=6`.

Now we need to XML encode this entire URL, which results in

`lookfor://3904?foo=this%26that&amp;bar=6`

Comment: Okay, that is a vote for the use of '&amp;' to protect the & delimiters and URL encoding for everything else. It is amazing how much even one reply confirming that I am not totally on the wrong path has reduced my stress level. Thank you zshift.

Comment: I restated ZShifts advice incorrectly. My comment should have been, "Okay, that is one vote for the use of URL encoding for the values of foo and bar and then XML encoding of the entire URI. It is amazing how much even one reply confirming that I am not totally on the wrong path has reduced my stress level. Thank you zshift."

Comment: Janet, if you feel that my response has answered your question in a relevant manner, would you be able to mark it as a such?